# trouble installing Gnome extensions

Tags: kali-linux, gnome, gnome-shell

Although I have installed all the required packages to install Gnome extensions, I still can't install additional extensions.
I use Gnome 45.3 on Wayland in Kali Linux
[image: My PC's information]

I also tried to install my favorite extension with the Gnome Extension Manager, but it didn't work either:
[image]

Using the activation widget on the GNOME website didn't help either.

I installed Gnome Extension integration. I thought maybe the problem was with the Firefox browser. So I used Chromium instead to no avail.

Please help me to solve this problem or explain how I can manually install the extension.

Comment: Kali does not really support GNOME with Wayland. The Kali website explicitly says, that if you switch to Wayland under GNOME: "This part is for experienced users only. If you follow those steps, we expect you to be able to fix issues that might arise by yourself."

Comment: I changed my OS to Arch and I'm using GNOME 46 but the problem still exists.